# File upload and download in vaadin

Tags: java, spring, maven, vaadin

Am very very new to Vaadin. Am setting up the project by looking into Github and other docs, where am using Spring-security, Vaadin, Maven.

I created sample vaadin-maven with spring security project. Now am getting login page then after suucessful login, am getting some MainView.java.

Am trying to change the upload .xls file and read that file and do some functionality and then download pop-up.

I have followed http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/other/upload , but errors. unable to reproduce my output.

For now, am able to read the file using path " final String FILE_PATH = "F://input.xls";" But, i need option to upload the file and then use that file for further functionality.

After the functionality completed, i need to download the file.

Please suggest me how can i browse the file and upload and use the uploaded file for ding some read and write operation and then download Vaadin.

Am having sleepless nights for this. Please suggest me how can i come out of this.
Here is my code:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@VaadinView(RoleAdminView.NAME)
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
public class RoleAdminView extends Panel implements View
{
   public static final String NAME = "role_admin";

@PostConstruct
public void PostConstruct()
{
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()).debug("POST");
    setSizeFull();
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setSpacing(true);
    layout.setMargin(true);
    layout.addComponent(new Button());
    layout.addComponent(new Label("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    layout.addComponent(new Link("Go back", new ExternalResource("#!" + 
   MainView.NAME)));

    setContent(layout);
    }

  @Override
  public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event)
       {
  }
   }
```

A big thank you in advance. Hope you guys sort out my issue :)

Comment: Please show your code for handling the upload. You will need to store the file serverside for processing. If it's in memory or in a temporary file depends on your requirements

Comment: Thanks for the response @AndréSchild . I have no idea how to handle the uploaded file in vaadin. i just created root.addComponent(new upload());. i stuck here. I am unable to move further :(

Comment: http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/other/upload  i used the source and added the code. am getting error on lineBreaker, and others.. i have no idea how to move.  please make my day free @AndréSchild :(

Comment: @AndréSchild i have updated the code. please have a look into that and suggest me how can i move forward

Comment: In your code there is no uploadbutton and also no handling of the upload

Comment: Did you check the [Vaadin book chapter on uploading](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-upload.html)?

Comment: @AndréSchild yes, no handling is there.. i don't know how to handle that in vaadin. that's why i posted my question here :(

Comment: Look in the book of vaadin and/or in the source http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/other/upload

Comment: You might want to have a read of this, very helpful and should get you started
https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-upload.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do,

```
public class RoleAdminView extends Panel implements View{

 //add a button view 
 //
  @Override
public void uploadFailed(Upload.FailedEvent event) {
    Notification.show(event.getFilename() + "----" + event.getMIMEType());
    //here it will show the error if upload failed
}

@Override
public void uploadSucceeded(SucceededEvent event) {
/// do your functionlity
 }
  @Override
public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename, String mimeType) {
   FileOutputStream fos = null;
   // do your functionality to save in any path or server path
    return fos; // Return the output stream to write to
 }

}
```

I hope this my help you :)

Comment: Thanks... i will check with  this... :)